# Colombeau generalized functions

Tags: textbook-recommendation, quantum-field-theory, generalized-functions

I'm currently reading some aspects of Colombeau generalized functions, and in almost all of his examples he discuss aspects of Quantum Field Theory, but then I go to some "standard" texts on QFT and I can not find any information (Ziedler only point out some similarities with Hörmander wave front sets; I can't find anything on Weinberg's book, or Folland).

Why is that? what is the major drawback about Colombeau "new" generalized functions to make it hard to find on physics books? or are there any standard physics books discussing it?

I know about the books "Nonlinear Theory of Generalized Functions" and "The linear theory of Colombeau generalized functions".

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to Weinberg: Colombeau's original work was published in 1984, Biagioni was 1990, and Colombeau's "Multiplications of distributions. A tool..." monograph was 1992. Weinberg's QFT books was 1995. It is possible that Weinberg had never heard of Colombeau algebra at the time of writing his book. // [James Vickers](http://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/jav/) is the only person I know who use Colombeau's theory to solve PDEs arising from physics.

Comment: QFT needs distributions. Namely, local averages of these generalized functions must give some numbers one can check against experiments. Smearing with a plane wave $exp(ipx)$ is also allowed if $p$ is not in the singular support of the Fourier transform. Colombeau generalized functions can be multiplied but the result is usually not a distribution and thus of little use to physicists.

Answer (score 4):

This recent textbook might be helpful:

[Geometric Theory of Generalized Functions with Applications to General Relativity,](https://books.google.nl/books?hl=nl&lr=&id=123uCAAAQBAJ) M. Grosser, M. Kunzinger, M. Oberguggenberger, and R. Steinbauer (2013).

> Over the past few years a certain shift of focus within the theory of
>   algebras of generalized functions (in the sense of J. F. Colombeau)
>   has taken place. Originating in infinite dimensional analysis and
>   initially applied mainly to problems in nonlinear partial differential
>   equations involving singularities, the theory has undergone a change
>   both in internal structure and scope of applicability, due to a
>   growing number of applications to questions of a more geometric
>   nature. The present book is intended to provide an in-depth
>   presentation of these developments comprising its structural aspects
>   within the theory of generalized functions as well as a (selective
>   but, as we hope, representative) set of applications, in particular in the context of general relativity.